# python3: different charset support

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, character-encoding, python-3.3

I am using python 3.3 in Windows 7.

```
if "iso-8859-1" in str(source):
    source = source.decode('iso-8859-1')
if "utf-8" in str(source):
    source = source.decode('utf-8')
```

So, currently my application is valid for the above two charsets only ... but I want to cover every possible charset.

Actually, I'm finding these charsets manually from the source of the website, and I have experienced that all the websites in the world are not just from these two. Sometimes websites do not show their charset in their HTML source! So, my application fails to move ahead there!

What should I do to detect a charset automatically and decode according to it?
Please try to make me aware in-depth and with examples if possible. You can suggest important links too.

Comment: The [`chardet`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) module tries to divine the encoding of its input, but it obviously gets it wrong sometimes.

Comment: I have already tried to look at `chardet` but I didn't get it on how to implement! Do python have any module regarding that? or it is impossible in python3?

Comment: There is a Python3 port as well. Google is your friend. http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/case-study-porting-chardet-to-python-3.html

Comment: Okay... I will try. but do we have other options to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) provides a function [`UnicodeDammit()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unicode-dammit) that goes through a number of steps<sup>1</sup> to determine the encoding of any string you give it, and converts it to unicode. It's pretty straightforward to use:

```
from bs4 import UnicodeDammit
unicode_string = UnicodeDammit(encoded_string)
```

If you use BeautifulSoup to process your HTML, it will [automatically use UnicodeDammit](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings) to convert it to unicode for you.

---

<sup>1</sup>[According to the documentation for BeautifulSoup 3](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit), these are the actions UnicodeDammit takes:

> Beautiful Soup tries the following encodings, in order of priority, to
>   turn your document into Unicode:
>
> - An encoding you pass in as the fromEncoding argument to the soup constructor.
> - An encoding discovered in the document itself: for instance, in an XML
>     declaration or (for HTML documents) an http-equiv META tag. If Beautiful
>     Soup finds this kind of encoding within the document, it parses the
>     document again from the beginning and gives the new encoding a try. The
>     only exception is if you explicitly specified an encoding, and that
>     encoding actually worked: then it will ignore any encoding it finds in the
>     document.
> - An encoding sniffed by looking at the first few bytes of the file. If an
>     encoding is detected at this stage, it will be one of the UTF-* encodings,
>     EBCDIC, or ASCII.
> - An encoding sniffed by the chardet library, if you have it installed.
> - UTF-8
> - Windows-1252

That explanation doesn't seem to be present in the BeautifulSoup 4 documentation, but presumably BS4's UnicodeDammit works in much the same way (though I haven't checked the source to be sure).

Comment: ... Which in turn falls back to `chardet` for any nontrivial encoding.

Comment: @tripleee It does eventually fall back to chardet, yes - but (unless you specify an encoding) the first thing it does is what magneto is trying to do, and as a widely-used library, it's likely to be more robust than a hand-rolled solution. I've edited my answer to provide a little more detail on UnicodeDammit's behaviour.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus Yeah, okay. I will try it. But I found one more problem now when I added `windows-1252` in above code, it's not decoding! So, what would be the problem? Any idea?

Comment: @magneto There could be any number of reasons. Just to give one example, the source for the page you're reading right now doesn't have a charset declaration (shame on you, stackoverflow), but *does* contain the strings `"iso-8859-1"`, `"utf-8"` and now `"windows-1252"`, so the code in your question will most likely fail to decode it properly. You really are better off using an off-the-shelf solution than trying to roll your own.